# EF Core 3.1 convert integer ToString could not be translated to sql

Tags: ef-core-3.1

I am using EF Core 3.1 (and I am aware that LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client).
However, I don't know why this is not working. It seems to work in other examples. This is my code:

```
          var test = Db.TblAppversiondates
            .Where(x => x.FkAppversionstatus.ToString() == "1")
            .ToList();
```

FkAppversionstatus is an integer (not nullable).

This is the error message I receive:

```
 The LINQ expression 'DbSet<TblAppversiondates>
    .Where(t => t.FkAppversionstatus.ToString() == "1")' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
```

Comment: Why are you using `ToString()` in the first place? Why not `x.FkAppversionstatus == 1` ? Even if it worked, the conversion would prevent the server from using any indexes. That's a bug in itself. The real solution is to avoid any conversions

Comment: Well I actually tried to do the following: 
`.Where(x =>  $"{x.Startdate.Day}-{x.Startdate.Month}" == "1-1")` or even `.Where(x => (x.Startdate.Day + "-" + x.Startdate.Month) == "1-1")` but both didn't work. I assume the root cause is because int to string conversion is not working.

Comment: Why do that either? What is the *actual* problem, what query do you want to perform? Don't explain what you tried, explain what the problem is

Comment: BTW `$"{x.Startdate.Day}-{x.Startdate.Month}"` is completely invalid. If you want to find records in a certain month trying to extract specific parts a) is database-specific and worse b) also prevents you from using any indexes. The easy and *fast* way would be to search for dates between the start and end of month, with eg `t.StartDate>=monthday1 and t.StartDate<nextmonthday1`. This is a range query that will use any indexes covering `StartDate`

Comment: If you have 1000 rows per month for 2 years, any query that applies functions to the `StartDate` column would have to scan 24000 rows. A range query on the other hand would only touch the 1000 rows for that specific month

Comment: This makes sense. I thought `$"{x.Startdate.Day}-{x.Startdate.Month}"` etc. is the best workaround for:  `x.Startdate.ToString()`. Since this also does not seem to work anymore.

Comment: It never did. Loading all the data to the client for filtering isn't viable for any production scenario - loading 100K rows when you only need 10 just isn't feasible. If you tried that same code in EF 6.2 or NHibernate you'd also get errors. EF Core 1.x used client-side evaluation only because it *couldn't* perform operations like `GroupBy`

Comment: Client-side evaluation generated runtime warnings in EF Core 2.x already.

Comment: But why isn't it possible to convert the datetime on the server side? The SQL function `CONVERT` would be able to convert the string to a date and compare it on the server side?

Comment: Because that's a bug. First of all, what string format would that use? A localized, unsortable one like `04/07/2020`? ISO8601? Most importantly **why**? If you want to search for a range, just use the correct conditions. In SQL you *wouldn't* use `CONVERT` if you wanted to search for a month's rows. You wouldn't even use `MONTH()`

Comment: There's no benefit from arbitrary string conversions while there are a *ton* of disadvantages. That's why such a feature was never implemented by any ORM